# Transform/map iterator<A> to iterator<B>

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Suppose there is a function taking `iterator<B>` and I have some (iterable) collection of `A`s.

```
void external_function(iterator<B> bit);
```

Furthermore I have a function to convert `A`s to `B`s.

```
B transform(A& a) { ... };
```

I would like some kind of wrapper iterator which iterates over all `A`s and gives `B`s instead.

```
iterator<B> transform(iterator<A> ait, UnaryOperator transformer);
```

Is there some function in boost that does that? Or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: Do you really need to transform the iterators? Can't you simply use something like `std::transform`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost has [boost::transform_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html); I suppose this is what you're looking for.